# Evernote API (python3): How to preserve whitespace while updating as enml code block?

Tags: python-3.x, api, evernote

I have following xml string:

```
myxml = """
<code>
if [[ -z $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS ]]; then
    if [[ -f ~/.dbus/session-bus/$(dbus-uuidgen --get)-0 ]]; then
        source ~/.dbus/session-bus/$(dbus-uuidgen --get)-0
        export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
    fi
fi
</code>
```

**When I try to update with enml code-block all of the whitespace beginning of the line gets lost.**

```py
import re
import evernote.edam.userstore.constants as UserStoreConstants
import evernote.edam.type.ttypes as Types
from evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes import NoteFilter, NotesMetadataResultSpec
from evernote.edam.type.ttypes import NoteSortOrder

from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient

client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=False)
note_store = client.get_note_store()

codeblock_tag = (
        '<div style="-en-codeblock: true; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 8px; '
        'font-family: Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, &quot;Courier New&quot;, monospace; font-size: 12px; '
        'color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-top-left-radius: 4px; '
        'border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; '
        'border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; background-color: rgb(251, 250, 248); '
        'border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">'
)


myxml = """
    <code>
    if [[ -z $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS ]]; then
        if [[ -f ~/.dbus/session-bus/$(dbus-uuidgen --get)-0 ]]; then
            source ~/.dbus/session-bus/$(dbus-uuidgen --get)-0
            export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
        fi
    fi
    </code>
"""

m = re.search(r'<code>(.*?)</code>', myxml, re.DOTALL)
code = (m.group(1))

code_new = ''
for line in code.split('\n'):
    line = '<div>' + line + '</div>' + '\n'
    code_new += line

code_new = codeblock_tag + code_new + '</div>'

ev_note = note_store.getNote('676767-56566-xxxxx',True, False, False, False)

ev_note.content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
ev_note.content += '<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM ' \
                '"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">'
ev_note.content += '<en-note>Here is the Evernote logo:<br/>'
ev_note.content += code_new
ev_note.content += '</en-note>'



note_store.updateNote(ev_note)
```

And in evernote it appears like this:

[image: evernote-code-block-screenshot]

**So How do I preserve white-space inside codeblock?**

Answer (score 0):

In your `myxml`, use [Non-breaking Space (U+00A0)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Comment: You mean with `&nbsp`? How? A simple example? Note: The whole enml (`ev_note.content`)  must be a string, otherwise evernote will reject upload

Comment: The simple example is `nbsp = u"\u00A0".encode('utf-8')`. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<code>` to `<code xml:space="preserve">`

Comment: Already tried that. `code = m.group(1)` preserving space fine. in-fact enml (en_note.content) preserve the space alright. It gets lost only after it updates to evernote. I also found out using `<pre>` preserves space but it adds an extra line space. I will try with `<div xml:space="preserve">`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the using `<pre> my code </pre>` around the code block. So code_new becomes:

```
code_new = codeblock_tag + '<pre>' + code_new + '</pre>' + '</div>'
```

Note: It's better than using no-breaking space. However non-breaking space works as well.